# second derivative at point where there is no first derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this HW where I have to calculate the $74$th derivative of $f(x)=\ln(1+x)\arctan(x)$ at $x=0$.
And it made me think, maybe I can say (about $\arctan(x)$ at $x=0$) that there is no limit for the second derivative, therefore, there are no derivatives of degree grater then $2$.
Am I right?

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ is very nicely behaved around $x=0$, derivatives of all orders exist.

Comment: If $\arctan$ has no second derivative at $0$, $f$ has none.

Comment: any idea on the HW I have?

Comment: @YoavR. I believe you have to use Taylor series about $x=0$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar unfortunately - we haven't learned taylor yet, and therefore I can't use it

Comment: Here is the result: [$$\frac{d^{74}}{dx^{74}}\ln(1+x)\arctan(x)$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=74th+derivative+of+ln%281%2Bx%29+arctan%28x%29%2C+x%3D0)

Comment: If you're going to change your questions, do so as an *edit* in the original post. Do not cross out your original question, and then post a different one. That makes answers to your earlier question seem irrelevant. By edit I mean at the end of your former post, which you can then title "EDIT: " or such. Better yet, post your new question as a separate question altogether.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Using all caps is just rude, it's not necessary.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey I need an expression - not a result....

Answer (score 2):

You're incorrect. The second derivative of $f(x)$ exists, and furthermore, $f''(0) = 2$.

In particular, there is no problem calculating the derivative at any order of the function $g(x) = \arctan(x)$. For example, $g(x) = \arctan(x) \implies  g'(x) = \frac 1{1 + x^2}$, and $g''(x) = -\frac{2x}{(1 + x^2)^2}$.

And so $g''(0) = 0$.

Note that in calculating higher order derivatives, we are not taking the derivative $g''(0) = 0$. Rather we are finding $g^{(n)}(x)$, and then finding its value $g^{(n)}(0)$.

Comment: When I try to calculate $lim (1/(x^2+1)))/x$ where x goes to 0, you see there is no two sided lim

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} \left(-\frac {2x}{x^2 + 1}\right) = \frac 01 = 0$, from either direction. It is continuous at $x = 0$ and in any interval about $0$.

Comment: ok, I'vw got it, it was a stupid mistake

Comment: We all do that Yoav (make mistakes)! So join the club! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To get an *expression* for the $n$-th derivative, you can use the [Leibniz Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)
$$(fg)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}.$$

Here $h^{(i)}$ denotes the $i$-th derivative of $h$.

Comment: I know that rule, but I need to simplify that expression... this is still homework

Answer (score 0):

Use Taylor series:
$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
$$\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
so
$$f(x)=\log(1+x)\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+m+1}\frac{x^{n+2m+1}}{n(2m+1)}$$
You want to compare this with
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^{k}\ .$$
To obtain the 74th derivative you have to compare the terms of degree 74 of the previous series:
$$\sum_{n+2m+1=74}\frac{(-1)^{n+m+1}}{n(2m+1)}=\frac{f^{(74)}(0)}{74!}\ ,$$
and thus
$$f^{(74)}(0)=74!\sum_{n+2m+1=74}\frac{(-1)^{n+m+1}}{n(2m+1)}$$

Comment: Great, except unfortunately, I can't use Taylor(we haven't learned it yet)

Comment: Ops! I didn't read carefully the question. In any case I hardly see  a reasonably efficient way to do similar computations without Taylor :/